# CMake error for OpenCV compilation in Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, cmake, mingw

I am trying to build the files in the "Source" folder to the "Build" folder using CMake in order to build OpenCV program in Eclipse. But I am facing the following error:

> The C++ compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple
>     test program. It fails with the following output:
>     Change Dir: C:/opencv/mbuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>     Run Build Command:"C:/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" "cmTC_03910/fast"
>     CMake Error: The source directory
>     "C:/opencv/mbuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_03910/fast" does not exist.
>     Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
>     CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
>     Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:93 (project)

I have installed MinGW several times along with CMake also, but still getting the same error.

Please help me out!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your CMakeLists.txt otherwise we won't be able to see where the error may come from. Did you check whether the folder "C:/opencv/mbuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_03910/fast" existed ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Surneef. I don't know exactly where to find CMakeLists.txt. Moreover that folder does not exist. What shall I do now ?

Comment: How can you use CMake to build a program if you don't have a CMakeLists.txt ? It should be with your sources (or in a parent folder)

Comment: Yes I am sorry, it's present in the Sources folder

Comment: I had sometimes a similar problem because of my Antivirus. Can you disable it temporarily?

Comment: @Sunreef: this compilation error is part of compiler detection mechanism in CMake, occured at first `project()` call in *CMakeLists.txt*. Unless cmake script sets incorrect compile flags or other compiler settings, the error has nothing common with *CMakeLists.txt* content. It is unlikely that OpenCV [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) is incorrect.

Comment: Shall I again download OpenCV version then ?

Comment: I am not using any antivirus, opencv 3.1, cmake-3.4.3-win32-x86, mingw-get-setup

Comment: @AshutoshMishra Possibly a firewall? Before blaming OpenCV, try first with a simple project. One empty dummy.cpp file and a 3-line CMakeLists.txt containing `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4) project(dummyProj) add_library(dummy SHARED dummy.cpp)` When you answer to me please add `@Antonio` to notify me.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra Could you please provide cmake command you're using to generate the project?

Comment: Thanks guyz, the problem was resolved !! There was an error in opencv version I downloaded hence I deleted it and therefore installed it again which ran perfectly fine

Comment: @AshutoshMishra You should answer your own question, although it would have been more informative understanding what was exactly wrong with the version you downloaded. What could have helped is also that you restarted from a clean build directory.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at this tutorial [PyIMageSearch opencv install](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/)
if you are using opencv version 3.1 you should set 
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \  instead ON
I solved problem with this way